# Concatenating C strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcat

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <string.h>
    int main(void){ 
    char pos[4][4];
    char loc[4];
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        pos[i][0]=4;
        pos[i][1]=4;
        pos[i][2]=4;
        pos[i][3]=4;
    } loc[i]=" ";
    strcat(loc[i],pos[i]);
}
```

I am trying to save all the contents of pos[i] in a concatenated
string. I am not sure how to go about this.  I would appreciate any tips.

Comment: You have multiple problems with the code you show. To start with the integer `4` is not a printable character, in [ASCII encoding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) it's the special `EOT` (end of transmission) character. Then when the loop is over, the variable `i` is `4` which is out of bounds for your arrays. And you write the *pointer* to the string literal `" "` to `loc[i]` which is not the same as the *character* `' '`. Lastly, the `strcat` function expects both its arguments to be valid strings, which in C means a sequence of chars terminated by the `'\0'` character.

Comment: ...and `loc[]` must be big enough to hold its original string, the concatenated string, and a string terminator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapted code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char pos[4][4];
    char *loc;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        pos[i][0] = 'a' + i;
        pos[i][1] = 'a' + i;
        pos[i][2] = 'a' + i;
        pos[i][3] = 'a' + i;
    };

    loc = (char *) pos;
    for (i = 0; i != sizeof(pos); i++) {
        fputc(loc[i], stdout);
    }
    fputc('\n', stdout);
    /* output: aaaabbbbccccdddd */

    return 0;
}
```

`pos` is already the concatenation you are looking for.

`pos` is the address of a memory chunk of contiguous characters
and could have been declared and initialized this way:

```
char pos[4][4] = {
    { 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a' }
  , { 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b' }
  , { 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c' }
  , { 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd' }
};
```

or this way (with a likely warning from the compiler):

```
char pos[4][4] = {
    'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'
  , 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'
  , 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'
  , 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd'
};
```

The two dimensions are just a view over `pos`, it can be flattened: `(char *) pos`.

If you need a flattened copy:

```
char cpy[sizeof(pos)];
memcpy(cpy, pos, sizeof(pos));
```